# For K observations, make N variables into 1 variable of dimension KxN

Tags: r

i am preparing dataset for plsr() in the pls pacakege in R.
My dataset A is imported as 62 obs.of 2001 variables. 
To run that plsr function. I have to make 2000 variables into 1 variable which has a dimension of 62 x 2000. 
So that the dataframe B has 62 obs. of 2 variables. One variables has a dimension of 62x1, the other has a dimension of 62x2000
how to do this in R? Please....
THANKS!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
  cbind( resp=dfrm[ , 1, drop=FALSE], mat = as.matrix(dfrm[, 2:2001] ) )
```

It's not clear what @LeeTaylor is expressing disapproval regarding. If you assigned such an object to the name `mydat` and ran:

```
  plsr(resp~mat, data=mydat)
```

.... I think there would be a reasonable chance of success. This remains untested in the absence of a proper example, the responsibility for which lies with the questioner.

Comment: Yeah, "Perhaps" is what I sometimes use. In other cases I use "In the absence of a proper example:".